# Redirect to a custom error catching page in vps but work in simple host

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I have an asp.net webform application that contains web api 2 (rest api) to share data. Recently I've moved from a simple host to a VPS with windows server 2012. the problem is, when the site was on the host everything works, but in VPS rest api doesn't work (other part of website like user login, database fetching and showing data, etc work except web api urls)

When I type the url of api it redirect to a custom error page which I've set for catching exceptions and I don't know what is wrong with it.

I've searched a lot but cannot find anything to help me, is there any special configuration for IIS or ASP.net to work with web api 2? or something else which I've missed?

I should mention that I use IIS 8, ASP.net 4.5

web.config Content:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=P;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Panel/Login" timeout="90" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>

  <location path=".">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
      </customErrors>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="panel">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="Pages/Panel/404.aspx" />
      </customErrors>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="adminpanel">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="Pages/AdminPanel/Admin404.aspx" />
      </customErrors>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*?)/?Default\.aspx$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Lower Case URLs" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="WebResource.axd" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)/$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <add name="CAPTCHAHandler" verb="GET" path="/CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.captchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" /> 
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <location path=".">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="panel">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="/Pages/Panel/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="adminpanel">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="/Pages/AdminPanel/Admin404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @TirthakShah, please do not use inline code formatting for non-code, and remove noise in posts, like "thanks in advance".

Comment: Show you web.config, provide some error details. Make sure that IIS is configured properly.

Comment: @Kamo if IIS is not configured correctly why other part of website works? Add web.config content now.

Comment: It is often a case of handling requests which are specific for WebAPI. Can you provide some error details(HTTP code etc).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any error details, the only thing I know is, it is redirected to a custom page which I defined for exception catch section ! I don't know where it goes to catch !!! because my API doesn't contains any thing !!! only Login and other page contain try catch which are irrelevant to API !!!